# Extracting data from JSON issue

Tags: php, json, youtube, youtube-api

I am trying to get some information about YouTube channel's from the YouTube API.

This is an example the output (using Google's channel), http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/Google?alt=json

I am getting the JSON using this:

```
$json = file_get_contents("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/Google?alt=json");
$data = json_decode($json, true);
```

I uploaded the output of `var_dump($data);` to pastebin: http://pastebin.com/CWA7YYGi

What I want to get is `totalUploadViews` from `yt$statistics`.

What I have tried so far is:

```
echo $data['yt$statistics']['totalUploadViews'];
```

But this gives me an error: `Notice: Undefined index: yt$statistics`

Not sure what I am doing wrong, would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`yt$statistics` is itself a value of a parent array.  Try

```
$data['entry']['yt$statistics']['totalUploadViews'];
```

Answer (score 1):

The `yt$statistics` is a key in the array of `$data['entry']`.

Answer (score 0):

do this:

```
$json = file_get_contents("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/Google?alt=json");
$data = json_decode($json, true);
echo $data["entry"]["yt\$statistics"]["totalUploadViews"];
```

the "\$" just escapes the harmful **$** from parsing.